# error in running jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I installed anaconda prompt on my computer and then tried to run the following in windows
C:\Users\Richard Boire>jupyter notebook

Listed below is the error message
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: where is `conda.exe` located?

Answer (score 0):

It's a typical message telling you that windows cannot find the executable corresponding to the keyword 'jupyter' you told it to execute.
The solution is to add the absolute path of jupyter.exe in "PATH" variable in environment variable:

[How to set the path and environment variables in Windows](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

For me, the installation path is: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter.exe

What you need to do is to add C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter.exe
to the PATH variable.
Note that if the PATH variable already has value assigned. First add a separator ";", then append the new path after the separator .